# UbuntuServer 16.04 VirtualBox Machine - Emergency Mode for Network Interfaces

Tags: virtual-machine, ubuntu-server, ifconfig

I'm using a virtual machine with Ubuntu16.04Server O.S. on a Windows host.
Everything was working perfectly but after switching off everything and then coming back to my virtual server, the machine doesn't start.

It shows:

> [FAILED] Failed to start Raise network interfaces. See 'systemctl status networking.service' for details.

So the system goes in **Emergency mode!**
By typing `journalctl -xb`, I can see the following issue:

```
...
ifup[1987]: Cannot find device "ens33"
...
ifup[1987]: Failed to bring up ens33.
systemd[1]: netowrking.service: Main process exited, code=exited ....
```

So I find my **failed to start Raise network interfaces**

```
Subject: Unit networking.service has failed
Defined-By: systemd
```

By typing `ifconfig` I see only the `lo` interface. No `ens33` is shown.

In my `/etc/network/interfaces` I have also the 2 rows:

```
auto ens33
iface ens33 inet dhcp
```

By typing `lshw` I have the following output related to the network:

```
*-network DISABLED
    description: Ethernet interfaces
    product: 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 3
    bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
    logical name: enp0s3
    ...
    ...
    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full.......
```

So if I run `ifup ens33` I have the error

```
Cannot find device ens33
Error getting hardware address for "ens33": No such device
```

The virtual machine has the default ethernet card Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (82540EM) connected as NAT.

It is completly stuck and I can't go forward, only **emergency mode**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution:
The issue should seems to be related to a mismatch of the ethernet card, and my solution was:

changing card on the virtual machine
entering in emergency mode
Editing the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, by changing the ens33 interface parameters and adding the new eth0 interface:

```
auto ens33
iface ens33 inet manual

auto eth0
iface eth' inet dhcp
```

At this point by restarting the network service I could see the interface up.

After it was necessary the editing of the `/etc/default/grub` file, changing the line from

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
```

Then I ran following commands:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```